# How to add same attributes in two different path - odoo xpath

Tags: python, xpath, odoo

How can i add same attributes in two different path in same form
i was try to separate by "|" but it working just with the first path

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='product_id'] | /form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="before">
              <field name="barcode_id"/>
              <field name="publisher"/>
          </xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this kind of XPath :

```
/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']//field[@name ='product_id' or @name='name']
```

Comment: they are not in the same path so this one is not working

Answer (score 0):

Wiest,

AFAIK In odoo, it's forbidden functionality that doesn't consider multiple XPath correspondence.

In the alternative, you could override `fields_view_get` and use XPath through lxml library.

Thanks